# Connect remotely with GDBSERVER to pid

Tags: debugging, gdb

When I run gdbserver to listen for port and connect remotely with gdb:

Gdbserver command:
`gdbserver --multi 0.0.0.0:4444`

Gdb command:
`target remote 192.168.1.99 4444`

In gdb . How can I connect to pid with `pidof(PROCESS_NAME)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options there, you could attach to a running process with GDB server or spawn it.

#### Attach to a running process

`gdbserver 0.0.0.0:44444 --attach <PID>`

or run GDB server and then from the connected GDB client lunch

`attach <PID>`

#### Spawn the process with GDB server

`gdbserver 0.0.0.0:44444 <program> <args>`

If you need a list of running process on the remote machine, you can lunch `info os processes` from your GDB client once connected to the remote server.